# What is the meaning of "_="?

Tags: environment-variables, set

After I run the `set -a var=99`, I can find a sentence in the output of `set`:

```
...
TERM=xterm
UID=0
USER=root
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
_=var=99
colors=/etc/DIR_COLORS
...
```

Could anyone tell me what "_=" means?

I note that `echo $var` will give nothing. If I run the `set -a`, then the `set` won't include this variable again. What is happening?

Comment: Related:  [Bash: why isn’t “set” behaving like I expect it to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9255/23408)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `_=` at the start of a line in the output of plain set means that there is a variable called `_` (underscore) in bash. And its value is what follows the `=`. Like setting a variable named `test_var` to `12345` will yield (in bash):

```
$ test_var=12345

$ set | grep test_var
test_var=12345

$ declare -p test_var
test_var=12345
```

That special bash variable will be set to the last argument of the previous line:

```
$ echo "Testing some" "values" "in the shell" "(only bash)" "_=myvar=hello"
Testing some values in the shell (only bash) _=myvar=hello

$ echo "$_"
_=myvar=hello

$ echo "Testing some" "values" "in the shell" "(only bash)" "_=myvar=hello"
Testing some values in the shell (only bash) _=myvar=hello

$ declare -p _
declare -- _="_=myvar=hello"
```

Note the **two** `=` in that output.

---

## Longer description

When you execute `set -a var=99`, **three** distinct things happen (related to your question):

1. A set option (`-a`) (reverse by doing `set +a`) to export vars.
2. Positional parameters are "set" to what follows the options (`$1` set to `var=99`).
3. The shell variable underscore `$_` is set to the last parameter (expanded).

---

## set -a

The execution of `set -a` marks **all** subsequent (new or changed) variables as exported (in all shells, except `csh` and some related shells).

```
$ set -a
$ myvariable=wer
$ env | grep myvariable
myvariable=wer
```

To recover from this setting, just change the `-` to a `+`:

```
$ set +a
$ unset myvariable              # to erase it from the environment if it
                                # was exported before the change of set +a
$ myvariable=456544654          # A new value of the variable.
$ env | grep "variable"         # No output means the var does not exist
                                # in the current environment
```

## set var=99

Which should actually be `set -- var=99` to avoid interpretation of an option (and set has a lot) with values that start with a dash (`-`).

Sets the list of arguments (the list of positional parameters) to that after the `--`. That is valid in all reasonable shells (not in csh et al).
Positional arguments are printed with "$@" (or similar "$*", not equal).

```
$ set -- a=1 b=2 c=3
$ echo "$@"
a=1 b=2 c=3
```

#_=last_argument
And, the value of the internal shell variable `_` change to the last argument of the executed line. That is **NOT** true in almost all shells (jsh, ash, yash, dash, lksh, mksh, ksh93, attsh and of course csh and tcsh) except bash.

```
$ echo one two last argument
one two last argument

$ echo "$_"
argument

$ echo This is a new: last_argument
This is a new: last_argument

$ echo "$_"
last_argument
```

Please note that the value in `$_` is the value after expansion:

```
$ a="A New_Argument"
$ echo Something else to test: "$a"
Something else to test: A New_Argument

$ echo "$_"
A New_Argument
```

That's why when you execute:

```
$ set -a myvar=99; set | grep 'myvar'
_=myvar=99
```

You get a description of the shell variable '$_'. This also works:

```
$  set -a myvar=99; declare -p _
declare -- _="myvar=99"
```

Answer (score 41):

The underscore is actually a special shell variable. What you are seeing here is the underscore (`_`) variable with a value of `var=99`. It is readonly, and maintained by the shell. It is:

- Set at shell startup, containing the absolute file name of the shell or script being executed as passed in the argument list.
- After that, it expands to the last argument to the previous command, after expansion.
- When checking mail, this parameter holds the name of the mail file.
- It is also set to the full pathname of each command executed and placed in the environment exported to that command.

Your example falls into the second category. You typed:

```
set -a var=99
```

So the last argument there was `var=99`, and that was the *value* you were setting (you weren't setting `var` to `99`). Hence, `_` was set to that. And that is what is being reported:

```
_=var=99
```

It's a bit confusing, but the first `=` indicates the assignment to the variable `_`, and the second is part of the value.

It is also worth mentioning that the `-a` option to `set` will cause *all subsequently defined variables* to be exported.

Answer (score 17):

The right answer would depend on the shell you're using:

- for [`bash`](https://www.mylinuxplace.com/bash-special-variables/), whatever @BobEager said applies
- for [`zsh`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell), it is only set to the last argument of the previous command, and to the full pathname of the command in the command's environment
- some shells like [`dash`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129280/106927) only set this variable when running an interactive session

There may be other particularities in other shells as well. As such, `$_` is [not defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_05_03) in POSIX, so one should be aware of potential portability issues when using it.

Side note: if your intention is to assign the value of 99 to `var` and make it available in the environment of subsequent subprocesses, the correct syntax to achieve this is:

```
export var=99
```

Comment: An also correct syntax is `unset var;set -a; var=99`. Works in all resonable shells (not csh et al).

Comment: @Arrow Although according to the last line of [Bob Eager's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/377620/73128) this would make _all_ variables subsequently set/modified exported, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 8):

> And I note `echo $var` will give nothing. 
>   … 
>   What’s happen?

In the not-so-fine print of [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), we find

> **`set`** [**`--abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT`**] [**`-o`** *option-name*] [*arg* …]
>   **`set`**  [**`+abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT`**]  [**`+o`** *option-name*] [*arg* …]
>
>   ︙
>   When options are specified, they set or unset shell attributes. 
>     Any arguments remaining after option processing are treated
>     as values for the positional parameters and are assigned, in order,
>     to
>   **`$1`**
>   ,
>   **`$2`**
>   , …
>   `$n`
>   .

Which means, `set -a var=99` doesn’t set environment variable `var` to `99`;
it sets `$1` to `var=99`. 
Try `echo "$1"` or `echo "$*"` and you’ll see.